# How can I assign a variable in html and copy its value to clipboard

Tags: php, html, variables, copy, clipboard

I have working code where I copy value by inserting it to  html text box
my present process is

1-saving image url to php variable $url 
2-then echoing $url to html text box then
3- copying it to user's clipboard

i just want to remove my second step and want any other way to get cpoied it to clipboard

I want to copy a value of my one of uploading image link to the user clipboard by saving it first to one php variable and then by echoing to html text box.

But I have a problem on copying it by html text box so I want to save it to variable in html and then copying it to user's clipboard.

Can any one here suggest a working method? 
Here's my working code:

PHP:

```
//upload.php
if($_FILES["file"]["name"] != '')
    {
        $test = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $ext = end($test);
        $name = rand(100, 999999999) . '.' . $ext;
        $location = './upload/' . $name; 
        $url= 'www.chat.com/upload/' . $name;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location);
    // echo '<img src="'.$location.'" height="150" width="225" class="img-thumbnail" />';

    // echo "\n\n\n\n$url";
} else {
    $url = "";
}
```

STYLE:

```
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 55px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 15px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input   type="text" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="myInput">

<button onclick="myFunction()">
    <h4 style="color:green;font-size:15px;"> 
        <b>Copy Img link</b>
    </h4>
</button>
```

SCRIPT:

```
function myFunction() {
    let inputEl = document.getElementById("myInput");
    inputEl.select();                                    // Select element
    inputEl.setSelectionRange(0, inputEl.value.length); // select from 0 to element length

    const successful = document.execCommand('copy');   // copy input value, and store success if needed

    if(successful) {

        //  alert("Copied IMAGE  URL PASTE IT TO SENDER : " + inputEl.value);
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to use the following JS function?

```
function copyToClipboard(elem) {
    // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
        }
        target.textContent = elem.textContent;
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
        succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch (e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }

    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = "";
    }
    return succeed;
}
```

You can use this function like the following:

```
copyToClipboard(yourImageLink);
```

or

```
copyToClipboard('<?php echo $url; ?>');
```

Here is a complete PHP source code[TEST code].

```
<?php
//upload.php
if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]) && $_FILES["file"]["name"] != '') {
    /*$test = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $ext = end($test);
    $name = rand(100, 999999999) . '.' . $ext;
    $location = './upload/' . $name;
    $url = 'www.chat.com/upload/' . $name;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location);
    // echo '<img src="'.$location.'" height="150" width="225" class="img-thumbnail" />';
    // echo "\n\n\n\n$url";
    */

    $test = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $ext = end($test);
    $name = rand(100, 999999999) . '.' . $ext;
    $location = './' . $name;
    $url = 'http://localhost/' . $name;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location);
} else {
    $url = "";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Copy & Paste YOUR IMAGE LINK </title>
    <style>
        .button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 55px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 15px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body >
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"><h4 style="color:green;font-size:15px;"><b>Copy Img link</b></h4></button>
</form>

<input style="width: 1px; height: 1px; opacity: 0;" type="text" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="myInput">

<script>
    function copyToClipboard(elem) {
        // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
        var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
        var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
        var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
        if (isInput) {
            // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
            target = elem;
            origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
            origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
        } else {
            // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
            target = document.getElementById(targetId);
            if (!target) {
                var target = document.createElement("textarea");
                target.style.position = "absolute";
                target.style.left = "-9999px";
                target.style.top = "0";
                target.id = targetId;
                document.body.appendChild(target);
            }
            target.textContent = elem.textContent;
        }
        // select the content
        var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
        target.focus();
        target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

        // copy the selection
        var succeed;
        try {
            succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
        } catch (e) {
            succeed = false;
        }
        // restore original focus
        if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
            currentFocus.focus();
        }

        if (isInput) {
            // restore prior selection
            elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
        } else {
            // clear temporary content
            target.textContent = "";
        }
        return succeed;
    }

    function myFunction() {
        let ele = document.getElementById('myInput');
        const successful = copyToClipboard(ele);
        if (successful) {
            alert("Copied IMAGE  URL PASTE IT TO SENDER : " + ele.value);
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/qpT7sgdwhWhZ)

I hope it would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: my friend where to use this function can u send me full updated code

Comment: @animeshsoni, Added a complete code. Please test it out. Thank you.

Comment: hey this form is my problem 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="myInput"> i want to remove this from my code   u find it in my html section

Comment: @animeshsoni, what is your problem actually? You said that you want to copy the uploaded image link to the clipboard?

Comment: my code was working means by tht i was copying img urk to clipborad but it wan showing a form where user comes every time when it press enter button of his mobile as screen is having one message box and one extra this image url adress carrying box so i am luking for a method by which i can copy url of uploading image to user's clipboard without using this box so my screen will have only one box in it i.e message box and i think it will be possible by saving url of my image firestly to one php varable which i donnd then frm thr to one  html variable and then to user's clipboard .

Comment: presently i was doing it by saving image url to one php variable then echoing it to html form and then copying it to user's clipboard ........my problem is second step i.e i don't want to echo it to html form i want any other way to copy that to clipboard and the whole process not have any html form box in it .

Comment: @animeshsoni, Updated source code. Please test it out. I am sure this will be the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @animeshsoni, how about my code? Is it working as expected?

Comment: its reloding on click on copy link there no any method to get it without reloading as reloading will remove all previous work as site is dealing with realtime chat

Comment: @animeshsoni, updated! Please add an HTML attribute type="button" in "Copy" button or move it outside of form.

Comment: @animeshsoni, I can't find my code inserted. You seem not to apply properly?

Comment: i inserted as it is

Comment: okhhhhhhh frnd no issueeee u just want vote i"ll give it be happy and be safe from covid